# How to Archive a Dynamic (PHP) Website as Static HTML?

Tags: php, caching, web-scraping, render, static-html

We're in the process of shutting down [The Conversations Network](http://conversationsnetwork.org/) (including the [IT Conversations](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/) podcast). The plan is to render a static-HTML version of our websites for permanent hosting at the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/index.php).

What's the easiest way to generate static HTML from the roughly 5,000 dynamic pages currently generated dynamically from PHP?

I know we could tweak the code to cache the PHP output, write it to files, then walk the sitemaps to generate every page. But I wonder if there are any options we should consider. Any tools for doing this and scraping the HTML as-is? (Something other than Acrobat Pro?)

Unfortunately, we also have a fair number of Ajax calls, which are going to make this more difficult. I imagine we'll have to un-Ajax them first.

Comment: Maybe the folks at the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org) will have good ideas.

Comment: If Ajax calls are POST calls, you're screwed. There is a benefit to design websites so that they work statically, especially for archiving. E.g. if you have a website with valuable content. But it's a design decision, if you need that later on, there is some work to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great piece of software called "[Teleport Pro](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/home.htm)" (payware unfortunately), and it can create browsable/duplicated copies of a website. Which, once uploaded to a server, should work exactly the same as the original site.

Things to keep in mind though when your creating static html from dynamic pages are;

- Your current ajax calls need to be un-ajaxed (as you said yourself)
- .htaccess settings, mod_rewrite for example can make your static files worthless. Because links might not work.

But "Teleport pro" is a real solid program which is around for quite some time. I have used it in the past and will probably use it again.

---

Another approach might be the php module "php-apc" which creates a cache. In this case u would need to crawl the whole site, before a complete cache is created. Im not TOO familiar with it, but an install is easily done, and you could see if the generated files are of any use.

Comment: apc caches not rendered pages but php code thus this wouldn't work

Answer (score 5):

It might not be what you are looking for; but [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) will browse your website for links and save the HTML-version of it. This mirror will include all static content that is linked, such as images, css and javascript.

The only problem I can think of is if your AJAX-script is pulling vital data from a server that, but perhaps HTTrack has a setting for that.

Comment: Httrack has a lot of options to offer, however for Ajax calls it's far from straight forward.